# Почему не запускается Apache в MAMP (MacOS Catalina)?

Tags: apache, mamp

Ребята помогите поднять Apache на 80 порту. При запуске сервера в MAMP показывает ошибку - Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.

Предистория такая: вчера вечером работало все ок, как часы. Сегодня я включил сервер XCode и после этого все полетело. Появился новая учетка при загрузке мака - "Other..." Кстати, как ее убрать, чтобы была только одна моя учетка? Но этот вопрос второстепенный, главное как Apache поднять на 80 порту. Что я только не делал. Останавливал, перезагружал Apache, даже переустановил его заново. Все равно пишет одну и туже ошибку. Как поднять его? На других портах работает вроде, но мне нужен 80. Что делать?

При команде Терминала - sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start
Получил...
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтото уже запущено и "держит" 80й порт.

1.1 Ещё вариант: Нет прав открыть сокет меньше 1024го (в linux это может делать "только рут")

2. Нет прав писать логи в тот каталог, который указан в конфиге.

Comment: На команду - sudo lsof -i:80 получаю - COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   6630 root    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   6631 _www    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   6632 _www    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   6633 _www    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   6634 _www    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   6635 _www    4u  IPv4 0x7d67819ca7d55fa3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: ну значит запущен уже httpd